# Comparing and remove repeated item from one List to another with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I'm comparing items in 2 lists and I will need to remove the element from the main list ( **#localInvCountryList** )

```
 $('#localInvCountryList li').each(function () {
                var txt = $(this).text();
                if (duplicate[txt])
                    $(this).remove();
                else                    

                 // Check duplicate countries in currentRegCountryList
                $('#currentRegCountryList li').each(function () {
                    var txt2 = $(this).text();
                    if (txt == txt2) {
                        console.log("Duplicaded");
                        //Remove from localInvCountryList
                       $('#currentRegCountryList li').remove(); // this removes the entire list instead of the repeated element!  
                    }
                })
                    // end check
                duplicate[txt] = true;
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this).remove()` instead of `$('#currentRegCountryList li').remove();`

To remove from localInvCountryList, find by text and remove.

```
$('#localInvCountryList li').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() === txt;
}).remove();
```

Comment: $(this).remove() will remove the element from currentRegCountryList and I need to remove from localInvCountryList

Answer (score 0):

I manage to do it with:

```
$('#localInvCountryList li:contains('+txt+')').remove();
```